# Microsoft SQL result rows to columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with an Microsoft SQL query. I would like to add columns from the result of the query to the each specfic row.

sql:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempResult
(
  rok int,  nazev varchar(500), kod int, JNC float, JPC float, CNC float, CPC float, ObchPriraz float, Marze float, vynos float
)
INSERT #TempResult Exec pOlapData 133,1,0,''
SELECT rok,nazev,JNC FROM #TempResult 

DROP TABLE #TempResult
```

This is the result:

[image: This is the Result]

And my goal is to add columns(maybe create another temp table): JNC 2013, JNC 2014, JNC 2015 ... to the each row with the same name from each year.

Expected result:

```
      name             | JNC 2013 | JNC 2014 | JNC 2015
  --------------------------------------------------------------
    name of the firm     number     number     number
```

Comment: If you have fixed number of expected `JNC` year columns, than a simple pure SQL pivot will work.  If you expect variable number of columns, then you will need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: It is fixed number of 4.  Could you help me with the "pivot" ? or show some example ? I would appreciate it :)

Comment: Check out my answer below.  It assumes that the `name of the firm` is actually the `nazev` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure SQL pivot query which will give you the result you want.  It assumes that you have 4 fixed columns from the years 2013 through and including 2016.  Of course, you may modify this to fit your exact needs.

```
SELECT nazev AS name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN rok = 2013 THEN JNC ELSE 0 END) AS 'JNC 2013',
    SUM(CASE WHEN rok = 2014 THEN JNC ELSE 0 END) AS 'JNC 2014',
    SUM(CASE WHEN rok = 2015 THEN JNC ELSE 0 END) AS 'JNC 2015',
    SUM(CASE WHEN rok = 2016 THEN JNC ELSE 0 END) AS 'JNC 2016'
FROM #TempResult
GROUP BY nazev
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  It is working perfectly fine. Now i can move on and modify it for my needs :) Thanks again.